# SharePoint 2010 3rd level drop-down menu

Tags: sharepoint-server, dropdown

I would like to create depper menus than just a 2 level menu. Even though I only see that I only can create 2nd level drop-down menus at the top bar.

So my question is: is there any way to create 3rd (or even 4th) level menu at the top bar in the SharePoint site?

I tried to google it and what I found is that I only can to do this via MasterPage template, which is not available in our current situation as it's seems to be disabled (I tried to go to SharePoint Designer 2010 and I wasn't able to find MasterPages option to the left, even though Publishing is enabled in features list).

Answer (score 0):

Try with site collection administrator permissions. This will help to view master page in designer.